# How can I avoid terminal messages screwing up vim?

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, tty

Sometimes I use vim in TTY1/2/etc. I am experiencing a problem with this. Messages such as the following keep flooding my terminal:

```
[ 1050.29303] wlp3s0: failed to set TX queue parameters for AC 2
[ 1059.29340] wlp3s0: failed to set TX queue parameters for AC 2
[ 1020.12309] wlp3s0: failed to set TX queue parameters for AC 2
[ 1029.12899] something_else: some other logging message here
[ 1292.21300] yet_another_thing: hey look a distraction
```

This can be quite disruptive, especially when I'm using vim to work, and sometimes it even results in me screwing up my text without realizing it. Is there any way to eliminate messages like this, at least when using vim? Using `:redraw`, editing the messed up lines, etc. don't seem to make the messages disappear.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vim.  You should consider asking on [unix.se].

Comment: @SatoKatsura I'm aware that the problem isn't vim's, but I'm wondering if vim has a way to automatically clear the screen when this sort of message appears, or at least *some* way to let me clear the screen when these appear.

Comment: From Vim, you should be able to force a redraw with `Ctrl-L`.  `:redraw` does something else.

Comment: It didn't seem to work for some reason. However, using `:!clear` worked just now, so I might have to stick with that.

Comment: You do realize that `:!clear` runs an external command, right?

Comment: @SatoKatsura Yes, I do. It's the only thing that seems to work clearing the messages from vim.

Comment: So, wouldn't it make sense to not have `klogd` messages fighting with Vim instead of you having to clean  them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample of lines looks like kernel messages.

You can turn off output of **dmesg** messages by typing in terminal

```
sudo dmesg -D
```

This is a temporary solution and will work until the system is rebooted. For permanent disabling edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file to set `kernel.printk` parameter.

```
kernel.printk = 1 4 1 3
```

I've set the first digit to 1 as the third was 1. Read more about [kernel.printk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13023/217571) and [klogctl(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/klogctl) {see description of SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_OFF command}

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect output to a file in sh script.
In bash this would be using the redirect operator `>`.
If what you are trying to get rid of is standard output, the redirection arrow is defaulted to that. If the output is error output, this would be file descriptor 2 so the operand would be `2>`

for example if I was going to run a python script in the background while using vim I could run the script like this

`$ python3 script.py >stdoutput.txt 2>errors.txt`

Comment: Unfortunately, the text isn't coming a script I'm running in the background, it's system log / error output, so this isn't an option.

Comment: Do you know why you have system log info popping up in your terminal?

Comment: sorry, i should have read your question closer, I undestand now